# Why is property setter is defaulted to public

Tags: c#, .net

Why is the default access modifier of getters and setters is public and not private?

Comment: Because properties **are** public and therefore it assumes you want the getters and setters to be public.

Comment: @MatthewRz but  properties, like any other class member are defaulted to private.

Comment: It would really help if you'd be *very clear* about what you'd propose as the alternative. Would you expect a property declared public to have private getters and setters by default? In what way would it be public at that point?

Comment: I don't propose anything as an alternative, I wanted to know what is the reason for 'Default public'. But now I know I was wrong and the default isn't public at all.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `get` and `set` portions of a property are not defaulted to public, they are defaulted to whichever is the visibility of the property they belong to. The default visibility of the property iself is private, as for all other kinds of members.

Answer (score 0):

Because it's how `C#` was designed.

- Defined fields
- Define property to access that field

So *expected* default behaviour that you make field `private` and make property in a way to be able to `write and read` to the field from the caller (arbitrary, not only derived one), so the property **and** `get/set` methods (if not there is no any sense making property public) becomes `public`.

This is just *expected default* behaviour, and nothing else.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is because the property has own access modifier and in fact describes a set of two methods: SomeType getProp() and void setProp(SomeType). These methods are seen like the property by default. But if you want to change their visibility you can do it using additional modifiers(for example Prop{get;private set;}).